# Drupal 7 behind proxy

Tags: apache, proxy, drupal-7

Where can I setup the proxy address and port in Drupal, or in the Apache server, in order to use the upgrade and new module installation features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check [this response](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1238/update-status-behind-a-proxy) on Drupal Answers. This is the new Stack Exchange site dedicated to Drupal.